# Does there exist a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ of nonnegative reals such that $ \sum_{j \ge 0} a_{nj} = \frac{1}{n}$ holds for all naturals $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ of nonnegative reals such that

$$ \sum_{j \ge 0} a_{nj} = \dfrac{1}{n}$$

holds for all naturals $n$?

**My progress:** I could show that $a_n\le \frac{1}{2n}$. I am not sure if this is even useful.

Comment: In a sense, you're asking if there is a "uniform - in some sense" probability distribution on the integers, and so my guess is that the answer to this is "most likely no".

Comment: An observation: $a_0 = 0$. If it was positive, then the sum would exceed $1/n$ if $n$ was large enough.

Comment: @user180446 Why did you tag it with "algebra-precalculus"? Did you come across this problem in such a class, or are you hoping to avoid an analytical approach to this problem?

Comment: @Calvin Lin My classmate gave me this problem. And he claims to have a solution using "not so high level mathematics". Thus I added that tag. Thanks for your keen interest in the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M$ be the product of the first $N$ primes and for $0\le r<M$ define
$$b_r=\sum_{k\equiv r\pmod M}a_k\ge0$$
(without any convergence problems).
Then 
$$ b_0+b_d+b_{2d}+\cdots+b_{M-d}=\frac 1d$$
for all divisors $d$ of $M$. 
If we multiply each such equation by $\mu(d)$ and add, then we obtain
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{M-1}c_kb_k=\sum_{d\mid M}\frac{\mu(d)}d=\prod_{i=1}^N\left(1-\frac1p\right)$$
where
$$c_k=\sum_{d|k}\mu(d)=\begin{cases}1&k=1\\0&k>1\end{cases}$$
In other words,
$$b_0= \prod_{i=1}^N\left(1-\frac1p\right).$$
On the other hand, $b_0=\frac 1M$ - a contradiction contradiction already for $M=2\cdot3\cdot 5$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put
$$
f(z) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j} {\,a_{\,j} z^{\,j} } 
$$

Then the application of the  [Series Multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection) tells us that
$$
\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j} {\,a_{\,n\,j} z^{\,n\,j} }  = {1 \over n}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {f(\omega ^{\,k} z)} 
$$

Therefore
$$
\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j} {\,a_{\,n\,j} z^{\,n\,j} }  = {1 \over n}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {f(\omega _{\,n} ^{\,k} z)} \quad \left| {\;\omega _{\,n}  = e^{\,i2\pi /n} } \right.
$$
and we are looking for a function $f(z)$ such that
$$
\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {f(\omega _{\,n} ^{\,k} )}  = 1
$$
which means that the function takes on values over the roots of $1^n$ which sum to $1$ for all values of $n$.

Now, the roots corresponding to $k/n = 1/2, 2/4, 3/6, ...$ have the same value, as all those for which $k/n = const.$.
Consequently also the function will have the same value on those roots.

I am not an expert in the theory of functions, but definitely $f(x)$ cannot be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$a_{n,j}=\frac{1}{n+j}-\frac{1}{n+j+1}\geqslant 0$$
It is a telescopic sum :
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}a_{n,j}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+j}-\frac{1}{n+j+1}\right)=\frac{1}{n} $$

**EDIT :** If you have $\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}a_{nj}=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$. First notice that $a_0=0$ because for $n$ large enough, you would have $\frac{1}{n}<a_0$ and thus $a_0\leqslant\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}a_{nj}=\frac{1}{n}<a_0$. Let $\mu$ be the Möbius function, first
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}=\sum_{(n,j)\in\mathbb{N}^*\times\mathbb{N}^*} \mu(n)a_{nj}=\sum_{p=1}^{+\infty}a_p\sum_{d|p}\mu(d)=a_1$$
because $\sum_{d|p}\mu(d)=0$ if $p\geqslant 2$ and $1$ if $p=1$. But because of the prime numbers theorem we have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}=0 $$
(Go here for a proof : https://books.google.fr/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&pg=PA94&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false )
thus $a_1=0$. Now let $\left(b_n^{(p)}\right)=(a_{np})$ for all $p\in\mathbb{N}^*$, we have
$$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*,\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}b_{nj}^{(p)}=\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}a_{npj}=\frac{1}{np} $$
Thus $a_p=b_1^{(p)}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{np}=\frac{a_1}{p}=0$ for all $p\in\mathbb{N}^*$ which is not. Thus such a sequence can't exist.

Comment: I believe the index is $nj$ not $n,j$. IE $ a_4 = a_{2\times 2}  = a_{1\times 4} = a_{4\times 1}$

Comment: Oh, didn't see it this way

Comment: I edited my answer with the index $nj$.

Comment: How do you know that "sum of reciprocal of product of $r$ primes" tends to 0? In particular, the "sum of reciprocal or product of 1 prime" is infinite, so a subset is "reciprocal of product of first r-1 primes * sum reciprocal of remaining prime" which likewise is infinite.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow +\infty}p_r=+\infty$ so $\frac{1}{p_1\ldots p_r}\leqslant\frac{1}{p_r}\longrightarrow 0$, is that it ?

Comment: But you have sum of "product of r primes" right? IE when $r=2$, you want $ 1/(2\times3) + 1/(2\times 5) + 1/(2\times 7) + \ldots + 1/(3 \times 5) + 1/(3 \times7 ) + \ldots "$.

Comment: Yes, the sum does not equal $0$ but it converges : $\left(\frac{1}{p_1\ldots p_r}\right)$ is decreasing to $0$ thus because of the theorem on alternating series, the series $\sum\frac{(-1)^r}{p_1\ldots p_r}$ converges. Oh I see, was too fast.

Comment: @VVejalla My claim is precisely that "each term goes to infinity", where term r is "sum of reciprocal of product of $r$ primes". Specifically, $ \sum \frac{1}{p_i} \rightarrow \infty$ so $ \sum \frac{ 1}{p_ip_j} > \sum_{p_j \neq 2} \frac{ 1}{2p_j } \rightarrow  \infty$

Comment: Oh I see, I was confused about that. That makes sense now.

Comment: I found that the prime numbers theorem is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}=0$, it is more complicated but that solves the problem.

Comment: You have to justify all of your interchange of signs, because you are massively reordering the sequence, which does not converge absolutely. I suspect (but don't have a solid backing) that the equation leading to $\ldots = a_1$ is not valid.

Comment: I "think" there could be some possibility through the Moebius and/or other Number T. functions (+1). Please have a look to my answer, maybe you can get some hint to develop your answer better.

Comment: Don’t leave the wrong answer. Please delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Many beautiful solutions have been presented here. But I think this would be the most elementary one.

**Note:** This solution is not mine.

We will prove that $a_i=0$ for all $i\ge 0$. $a_0=0$ has already been proved in previous answers.
Begin by observing that
$$\sum_{\gcd(i,n)=1} a_i=\frac{\phi(n)}{n}$$
if $n$ is a square-free integer. Now choose a particular $m$ and set $n$ to be relatively prime to $m$(For example, choose $m=8$ then set $n=5$). Thus the LHS is at-least $a_m$. But the RHS can be made arbitrarily close to 0 because $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i=0$ where $p_i$ stands for the $i$-th prime.